# Use AlertDialog to get text synchronously

Tags: java, android, text, dialog, synchronous

How do I use AlertDialog to get text synchronously? For instance, I would want to do something like this:

```
  public String GetTextDialog()
  {          
    final EditText text = new EditText(activity);

    // Gets the chat
    final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    dialog.setView(text);
    dialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
        }
    });
    dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) { 
        } 
    });

    // Display
    dialog.show();

    // Return text after dialog is complete
    return text.getText().toString();
  }
```

**EDIT**: Would you consider this a better way:

```
interface TextHandler 
{ 
    public String Title(); 
    public void HandleText(String text); 
}

public static boolean ShowTextDialog(
        String title,
        String defaultValue,
        final TextHandler posButton,
        final TextHandler negButton,
        final TextHandler neutButton,
        int width
        )
{
    // Check for already existing dialog
    if(showDialog) return false;
    showDialog = true;

    // Verify context
    if(context == null) 
    {
        Log.e("Crystal", "Screen::ShowTextDialog No Context!");
        showDialog = false;
        return false;
    }

    // Verify we have buttons
    if(neutButton == null)
    {
        if(posButton == null || negButton == null)
        {
            Log.e("Crystal", "Screen::ShowTextDialog Must supply both postive and negative buttons!");
            showDialog = false;
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(posButton != null || negButton != null)
        {
            Log.e("Crystal", "Screen::ShowTextDialog Can't have neutral button with other type!");
            showDialog = false;
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Create the dialog
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    if(title != null) dialog.setTitle(title);

    // Create the chat
    final EditText text = new EditText(context);
    text.setSingleLine();
    if(defaultValue != null) text.setText(defaultValue);
    if(width != 0) text.setWidth((int)(width*context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));

    // Add text to dialog
    dialog.setView(text);

    if(posButton != null)
    {
        dialog.setPositiveButton(posButton.Title(), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                posButton.HandleText(text.getText().toString());
                showDialog = false;
            }
        });
    }

    if(negButton != null)
    {
        dialog.setNegativeButton(negButton.Title(), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                negButton.HandleText(text.getText().toString());
                showDialog = false;
            }
        });
    }

    if(neutButton != null)
    {
        dialog.setNeutralButton(neutButton.Title(), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                neutButton.HandleText(text.getText().toString());
                showDialog = false;
            }
        });
    }

    // Display
    dialog.show();

    return true;
}
```

And called like this:

```
private void GetUsernameDialog()
{
    ShowTextDialog(
            "Enter Username",                                                   // Title
            username,                                                           // Default value
            new TextHandler()                                                   // Positive button
            {
                public String Title() { return "Ok"; }
                public void HandleText(String text) { SetUsername(text); }
            }, 
            new TextHandler()                                                   // Negative button
            {
                public String Title() { return "Cancel"; }
                public void HandleText(String text) { }
            }, 
            null,                                                               // Neutral button
            200                                                                 // Width
        );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the dialog in an alternative thread with a Looper in it, terminating the looper on dialog dismissal, having the main UI thread wait on that other one... but this is such a convoluted design, God might just kill a kitten if you do that. May I ask why do you need synchronous data access? Is this just about convenience, or you have a design reason?

If it's about accessing state from before the dialog setup, then nested anonymous classes are your answer. You already have those in the snippet above; they have automagical access to the `final` variables of the nesting function and to members of the nesting class.

Comment: I want a function that can return text retrieved from the user. I don't need to use AlertDialog if there is something better.

Comment: GUI is asynchronous (event-driven) by nature. In addition, Android, unlike Windows, has no way to run a message loop inside a message loop. I understand what do you want; the question is - why?

Comment: I guess I could probably redesign my code to be asynchronous, but I hoped to have an easy function to call to be able to get text. If there is no easy way to do that, I can try another way.

Comment: What's so hard about event-driven programming? Get used to it, in Android (or any GUI system, for that matter) it's all around the place.

Comment: Still asynchronous. The string becomes available much later that GetUsernameDialog() returns. You've abstracted away some of the dialog stuff; but this is not an answer to your question as initially posed.

Comment: You are right, I guess I have decided that I won't use an synchronous system.